# Getting assets within fragements

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to parse an xml file in thread within a fragment.

Partial snippet of my code is :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
  mAdapter = new ListItemNearbyStoresAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mStoresByKey);

         setListAdapter(mAdapter);

         // Load the list of stores from hard coded xml
         loadStoresByThread(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    }

    private void loadStoresByThread(final Context ctx)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread()
            {

                public void run()
                {

                    try
                    {


                        Log.d(TAG, "In the thread");
                        String[] files = ctx.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.storefiles);
                       // String[] files={"s1.xml"};



                        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                        {

                            try
                            {
                                InputStream stream = getActivity().getAssets().open(files[i]);

                                 NearbyItemDomFeedParser parser = new NearbyItemDomFeedParser(stream);
                                ArrayList<Store> stores = parser.parse();
                                Log.e("no of fioles read","asd :"+stores.size());
                                mStores.addAll(stores);
                                cache.setItems(mStores);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Exception caught" + e);
                            }
                        }
}
}
```

Note this whole class extends a list fragment.

Is accessing the assets in correct within an fragment ?

Cause I am unable to read file.

There are no exceptions raised so I am unable to figure out the exact error.

But finally after parsing using a builder I get 0 items.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is accessing the assets in correct within an fragment ?

Use the `Activity` (`getActivity()`), not the `Application` (`getApplicationContext()`) and see if that helps. Unless you have very specific instructions from somebody who knows what they are talking about, never use `getApplicationContext()` in your app.

Comment: it helped me to get the to the root  of the problem .. Thank you

Comment: It did not work for me but why never use `getApplicationContext()`?